# CakePHP: how to get total number of records retrieved with pagination

Tags: cakephp

When you retrieve records using `$this->paginate('Modelname')` with some page `limit`, how do you get the total number of records retrieved?

I'd like to display this total count on the view, but `count($recordsRetrieved)` returns the number displayed only on the current page. So, if total number of records retrieved is 99 and `limit` is set to 10, it returns 10, not the 99.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can `debug($this->Paginator->params());`

This will give you

```
/*
Array
(
    [page] => 2
    [current] => 2
    [count] => 43
    [prevPage] => 1
    [nextPage] => 3
    [pageCount] => 3
    [order] =>
    [limit] => 20
    [options] => Array
        (
            [page] => 2
            [conditions] => Array
                (
                )
        )
    [paramType] => named
)
*/
```

The final code for PHP >=5.4:

`$this->Paginator->params()['count'];`

For PHP versions less than 5.4:

```
$paginatorInformation = $this->Paginator->params();
$totalPageCount = $paginatorInformation['count'];
```

Answer (score 8):

To get your answer go to he following link 
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html

use `pr($this->request->params)` you will find all the stuff of pagination

Answer (score 6):

For cake 3.x

you can use method getPagingParams

example:

```
debug($this->Paginator->getPagingParams());
```

output:

```
[
    'users' => [
        'finder' => 'all',
        'page' => (int) 1,
        'current' => (int) 5,
        'count' => (int) 5,
        'perPage' => (int) 1,
        'prevPage' => false,
        'nextPage' => true,
        'pageCount' => (int) 5,
        'sort' => null,
        'direction' => false,
        'limit' => null,
        'sortDefault' => false,
        'directionDefault' => false,
        'scope' => null
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I got the count from my controller*

This is for CakePHP 2.3. It uses a view helper, which is typically a no-no in the controller as it violates MVC, but in this case I think makes sense to keep the code DRY.

```
// Top of file
App::uses('PaginatorHelper', 'View/Helper');

// Later in controller method
$paginatorHelper = new PaginatorHelper(new View(null));
$records = $this->paginate();
$count = $paginatorHelper->params()['count'];
```

* I know the OP asked about from the view, but I figure if Arzon Barua's answer is helping people (though I think it only tells you the requested count, not the actual count as the OP wants), then this might help too.

Answer (score 0):

This way is getting a pagination information over controller.

```
class YourController extends Controller{
  $helpers = array('Paginator');
  public fn(){
    $view = new View(null);
    var_dump($view->paginator->params());
  }
}
```